# Is there a way to make tkinter show different labels when adding two variables to each other

Tags: python, tkinter

I just started learning python, and I am trying to do a basic calculator kind of thing that shows what compound it is when you add two elements together andI want this code to show "O2"  as a label when I input oxygen+oxygen or "H2" when I enter hydrogen+hydrogen and so on. but it shows "OO" and "HH" etc. right now. Is there a way to do what I want? Here's my current code:

```
carbon = "C"
oxygen = "O"
hydrogen = "H"


root = Tk()

e = Entry(root, width = 50)
e.pack()

def myClick():
    myLabel = Label(root, text =eval(e.get()))
    myLabel.pack()

myButton = Button(root, text="Calculate", command = myClick)
myButton.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you expect the user to enter something like `oxygen + oxygen`.
When that expression is evaluated with `eval(e.get())`, the two strings (`"O"` and `"O"` in this case) get concatenated, which basically means that the one is stuck right after the other (like two Lego blocks). The values of the string are not in any way added together mathematically.
What you want to do is create a new variable, then split it at the '+' sign and compare the outcome. I wrote some code to better explain this (everything is the same except the `myClick()` function:

```
from tkinter import *
carbon = "C"
oxygen = "O"
hydrogen = "H"

root = Tk()

e = Entry(root, width = 50)
e.pack()

def myClick():

    # This is the new section
    temp = e.get().split(sep='+') # this will return a list containing
    mystr = "" # empty string

    temp = [i.strip() for i in temp] # this will get rid of any space characters (.strip()) below and after the strings
                                     # if you want to remove specific characters, use .strip(chars=mylist)
                                     # include those characters in mylist

    if temp[0] == temp[1]:
        mystr = eval(temp[0]) + "2" # when both strings are the same
    elif temp[0] != temp[1]: # you could also use a plain 'else:' statement here
        mystr = eval(temp[0]) + eval(temp[1]) # when strings are different

    myLabel = Label(root, text=mystr)
    myLabel.pack()

myButton = Button(root, text="Calculate", command = myClick)
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you sir! This is exactly what I wanted. Sorry if I wasn't able to explain it correctly. English is not my main language.

Comment: How does this answer cater something like `carbon + oxygen + oxygen + oxygen`?

Comment: @acw1668 it won't :( but I assumed that it won't be needed since OP asked for 2 elements

Answer (score 0):

On your myClick() function you can use:

```
def myClick():
    text_entry = [str(i) + str(e.get().count(i)) for i in set(e.get())] #set keeps only different caracters
    text_entry = ''.join(res) #caracter before join can be replace with '+' or ' ' or any

    myLabel = Label(root, text = text_entry)
    myLabel.pack()
```

should work like this

Comment: `test_str` is undefined and I think it should be the result of `eval(e.get())`. Also  `''.join(res)` should be `''.join(text_entry)`.